# how can I know number of instruction access?

Tags: mips, cpu-architecture, instruction-set

I'm studying computer architecture. I'm confused about some quiz.
when executing `n` instructions in load-store arch.
`lw $t0, 32($s3)`
`add $t0, $s2, $t0`
`sw $t0, 48($s3)`
then what is number of memory access, and number of instruction access?

I think num of memory access is 2 and num of instruction access is 3. Is it right?

Comment: Yes. It is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's right, Just for the sake of understanding it better here is some explanation.

MIPS using *load word* instruction `lw` to read data word from memory into register and
*store word* `sw` to write a word in memory.

`lw $t0, 32($s3)`
This load a word from memory into register `$t0`

`add $t0, $s2, $t0`
This means you are on the register side no memory involved.

`sw $t0, 48($s3)` This store a word in memory.

You are using 3 instruction which two of them involve with memory access